# View inside a View and data synchronization

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am having one view where I need to display some Grid and TabControl. There is one column on a grid that should display something like a Note (Remark) property. Since this field can contain large amount of data, I am going to have one tab with TextBox control that should allow user to see/edit note, while grid column will show only a few first letters on the note.

I am going to post relevant parts only:

```
public classSomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        TabScreens = New List<ViewModelBase>();
        TabScreens.Add(new AnotherViewModel1());
        TabScreens.Add(new AnotherViewModel2());
    }

    List<ViewModelBase> TabScreens{get;set;}
}
```

SomeView xaml:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AnotherViewModel1}">
    <vw:AnotherView1 />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AnotherViewModel2}">
    <vw:AnotherView2 />
</DataTemplate>
```

AnotherView2:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text={Binding Note} />
</Grid>
```

AnotherViewModel2:

```
public class AnotherViewModel2
{
    public string Note {get;set;}
}
}
```

So TabControl on View is bound to TabScreens. DataTemplates ensure that both AnotherView1 and AnotherView2 will be loaded when SomeView is loaded. Each row in grid contains different remark. What is the cleanest way to synchronize SomeViewModel Remark and AnotherViewModel2 Remark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the 2 view models into a master view model with a single Remark property.  Don't introduce a need to synchronize if it's not necessary.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand. Can you elaborate a bit more your idea?